# Pi's static IP causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in my router's config page

Tags: networking, static-ip

I'm running Raspbian Lite on my Pi 2 and I decided to make it's IP static, so I could SSH into it easily, run Plex Media Server and a few other things that are easier to access if your IP does not change all the time.

Since my modem/router (a terrible Thomson DWG874B, provided by my ISP) does not have DHCP reservation (how doesn't it??), I had to configure the IP the "hard" way:

`$ sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Added the lines:

```
iterface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.10.15/24          # Desired IP
static routers=192.168.10.1                 # Router's IP
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4  # Google DNS
```

These lines are from some tutorial I've found somewhere in the Internet not long ago, with some adaptations to fit my needs.

I made sure that DHCP lease pool does not include that IP (it ranges from 20 to 254), and everything seemed to be ok.

Until a few minutes ago, when I tried to access my router's configs again, and I keep getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Then I unplug the Pi, everything's fine again. Conclusion: Pi is the problem.

What did I do wrong?

I have a NAS in the same network that I set a static IP as well and it just works, no complaints about it.

Comment: Consider a different static ip? possibly a ip address conflict?

Comment: There is absolutely no other device assigned to this IP. It's outside the DHCP range, and there is only one other static IP at `192.168.10.10`.

Comment: Be sure the Pi is the problem. Problably you did it but, plug again your Pi and check if the error is shown again. If the problem appears, check if your network works even if you can't access your router config.

Comment: @migrc yes, the problem is the Pi. The network/internet access is normal, nothing else has changed but the router's access. It is really the only thing I cannot access. Everything else works from any device, including the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your file. There'd be an 'n' in 'interface.'